# Sublime Text plugin class naming convention

Tags: python, sublimetext2, sublimetext, sublime-text-plugin

In order to create a minimalist plugin for simple tasks in Sublime Text, I do:

1. Add this line in `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User\Default (Windows).sublime-keymap"` (available from menu *Preferences > Key bindings - User*):

   ```
   { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+enter"], "command": "myplugin123_blah" },
   ```
2. I create a Python file with the **same name**, i.e. `myplugin123_blah.py` in
   `C:\Users\User\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User\`
3. I create the plugin code:

   ```
   import sublime
   import sublime_plugin
   import subprocess

   class Myplugin123BlahCommand(sublime_plugin.WindowCommand):
       def run(self):
           command = 'doanything'
           subprocess.Popen(command)
   ```

It seems that the "class name" should be:

- The `command` name, where each `_` is removed
- Each word (separated by `_` before it was removed) has to begin by an uppercase letter
- Add `Command` at the end of the class name

Thus: `myplugin123_blah` => `class Myplugin123BlahCommand`

**Is this correct (just found this with trial and error and looking at other examples)? Is this the general naming rule for subclasses of `sublime_plugin.WindowCommand` ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically this is approached from the other direction - writing a Python plugin with some Text/Window commands and then "translating" that name into one you can call from ST - but in either case, knowing the rules is helpful when you don't want a needlessly unreadable name in your Python code or keybindings etc.

The unofficial documentation (for ST3, which has the same rules as the deprecated ST2), explains it like this:
http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/plugins.html#conventions-for-command-names

> By convention, Sublime Text command class names are suffixed with `Command` and written as `NamesLikeThisCommand`.
>   However, command names are automatically transformed from `NamesLikeThisCommand` to `name_like_this`. Thus, `ExampleCommand` would become `example`, and `AnotherExampleCommand` would become `another_example`.
>   In names for classes defining commands, use `NameLikeThisCommand`. To call a command from the API, use the standardized `name_like_this`.

Which matches up with your discovery.

Comment: Is it necessary to suffix with Command. Works without too